# Azure AD roles claim missing in Token

Tags: azure-active-directory, access-token, roles, microsoft-identity-platform

I have an app where the AzureAD login is working fine. However, I would like to identify if the user is in a custom role defined on the App Registration.

I have added my user account to the custom role in the Enterprise Application linked to the App Registration.

The App Registration is set up with ID Token checked.

I have my program.cs with the following code:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
});
```

Yet when look at the User object, it has all my user information but no claim for roles.

Any idea why?

Thanks in advance,
Jake.

EDIT: Claims token screenshot (url instead of friendly name for roles, tid, etc.)
[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/enterprise-app-role-management

Comment: You didn't mention you added the role claim

Comment: so I have got it now to work. I think I had not granted any API permissions other than the default graph user read. But after I added another API permission explicitly it seems to work. Only issue now is that the claim shows a url instead of roles

So I see it as, 
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role: AppReg.Admin}

instead of
{roles: AppReg.Admin}

What am I missing?

Comment: Issue is resolved. Comments on the other message. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To get the Azure AD role claims in ID token, check the below:**

Create **App roles** in Azure AD Application:

[image]

**In Enterprise Application,** I added the role for a user:

[image]

Now, I generated **tokens via *Postman*** using below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
scope:ClientID/.default openid
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
grant_type:authorization_code
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

***When I decoded the ID token, roles are displayed successfully:***

[image]

The role claims will also be displayed in **access token**:

[image]

Now, I tried to sign-in with the user who is not assigned any roles in the application and the role claims did not display in the ID token:

[image]

To get Azure AD role claims using ASP.NET Core web app, refer this [**GitHub**](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/blob/master/5-WebApp-AuthZ/5-1-Roles/README.md) blog by aremo-ms.

In your **`Startup.cs`** file modify the code like below:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
                       JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false;
           services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            {
                                options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "roles";
            });

                   services.AddAuthorization(options => 
            {
                options.AddPolicy(AuthorizationPolicies.AssignmentToUserReaderRoleRequired, policy => policy.RequireRole(AppRole.UserReaders));
                options.AddPolicy(AuthorizationPolicies.AssignmentToDirectoryViewerRoleRequired, policy => policy.RequireRole(AppRole.DirectoryViewers));
            });
            }

// In code..(Controllers & elsewhere)
[Authorize(Policy = AuthorizationPolicies.AssignmentToDirectoryViewerRoleRequired)]
// or
User.IsInRole("UserReaders"); // In methods
```

**Reference:**

[Add app roles and get them from a token - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-apps)

Comment: so I have got it now to work. I think I had not granted any API permissions other than the default graph user read. But after I added another API permission explicitly it seems to work. Only issue now is that the claim shows a url instead of roles

So I see it as, 
{http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role: AppReg.Admin}

instead of
{roles: AppReg.Admin}

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you please add the screenshots of the claims added in Azure Ad app and decoded access token screenshot

Comment: After an Internet search I found the recommendation to change as follows

options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role";

This seems to get it to work with the isUserInRole method. 

However I am curious why I am getting a url in the first place. When I run the example from github, I get the word "roles" rather than "schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"

Comment: So did the GitHub sample work

Comment: Yes the git hub sample did work.....and it does give me the "roles" name correctly also. I was trying to integrate the code into my own project. But when I run that, it returns the URL instead. Am including the image in the original post.

Comment: Please refer the GitHub sample as that worked for me as well. Maybe there is some code error in your project which is causing the issue

Comment: Reading through the comments in the code it says - 
// This is required to be instantiated before the OpenIdConnectOptions starts getting configured.
// By default, the claims mapping will map claim names in the old format to accommodate older SAML applications.
// 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role' instead of 'roles'
// This flag ensures that the ClaimsIdentity claims collection will be built from the claims in the token

After adding JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultMapInboundClaims = false; it now shows as roles. Thanks!!