Using Entra authentication with load balancer: forwarded access token does not include roles claim
AWS ABL (Application load balancer) is used to authenticate app users. Identity Provider is Entra (Azure AD).
ABL forwards header x-amzn-oidc-accesstoken to the application, but roles claims are not included.
Is there a workaround to include roles into the access token? Or forward id token from ABL?

Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77041535/azure-ad-roles-claim-missing-in-token
