EntraID: how to pass application roles downstream
I am working on an SPA (Blazor wasm), that uses AzureAD/EntraID with "authorization code flow".
The app is hosted in an ASP.NET Core 8 Web API service, that exposes some simple APIs for now. I have configured the app to request and attach downstream access token (based on this). The access token is reaching the endpoint. So far so good.
But I also want to use application roles. I have configured them, and I do get them in the ID token (just for reference). But I need those roles on the backend side as well.
How can I include that (or any other claim for that matter from the identity token) into the downstream token?
[Update]
I have figured it out. The issue was that I requested the access token to something else. I had to do the following:

"exposed an API" for that application,
define a scope for that API
assign and approve that scope as grant
update the default access token scope in the options to the newly created one.

And now the roles are included in the access token because the token is intended for the same application. Indeed, roles unknown to the other API are useless to include.

Did you create the app roles and assigned to the user in Enterprise application?

Of course. The id token contains them. But the downstream access token doesn't.

Check this if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77041535/azure-ad-roles-claim-missing-in-token

Did you create 2 applications? Did you assign users for the backend app too?

No, it is a single application registration. But I have figured it out: see the update. Thank you for your effort.

Can I post it as an answer?

If you want to.

To get app roles in the access token, check the below:
Expose an API and add scope in the Microsoft Entra ID application:

Created App role:

Grant API permissions as below:

In the Enterprise application, assign a user to this app role:

For sample, generated tokens for the API via Postman by using below parameters:
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:authorization_code
client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
scope:api://xxx/.default
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms


When I decoded roles claim is displayed in the access token:

If still the issue persists, check below:

Make sure you are generating the token for the application where roles are created as roles are unknown to the other API to include it in token.
Expose an API, add scope and pass the scope to generate the token.
Check if the user is assigned with role.

